# thread in Java Swing don't work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I have some simple code with a `for` loop. In each pass of the loop I must increment the JProgressBar; however, this isn't working. See below:

```
public void atualizarBarraDeProgresso(final int valorGeral, final int valorAtual) {
    Thread threadProgressoCarregamento = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             jProgressBarPersistindo.setValue(valorAtual);
        }
    };
    threadProgressoCarregamento.start();
}
```

I'm calling the method "atualizarBarraDeProgresso" in a loop like below:

```
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(qtd);
for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) { 
    atualizarBarraDeProgresso(qtd, i + 1);
    doSomething();
}
```

But nothing happens with my progressBar.

Comment: Do you *really* want that many threads? In any case, I suspect the problem is that the *loop itself* happens on the ADT (i.e. in a "click handler") and *blocks* Swing UI interaction and updates until it completes. Consider using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) - using such correctly will likely eliminate all problems. Also, make sure to *only* update Swing objects on the ADT.

Comment: Are you calling repaint() on the containing JPanel after you set the value at any point? This may be all that's missing.

Comment: call the repaint() method, and by the way, the solution is very bad.

Comment: @user2246674  (polite cough) By 'ADT' DYM 'EDT'?  For the OP, a general tip.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, meant the EDT. Old/outdated names die way too slow and tend to unfortunately resurface. (Way, way back in the day I - possible incorrectly - knew it as the "AWT Dispatch Thread". Oh, good (hah!) old AWT 1.0 and threading ..) Thanks for the correction and clarification to the OP.

Comment: This is a funny inversion of the required logic: instead of ensuring that the modification of the Swing `Component` happens inside the EDT this code ensures that the modification is the only action *not* in the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a thread before a for statment. I hope it works

```
    progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    progressBar.setMaximum(qtd);

    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) { 
                atualizarBarraDeProgresso(qtd, i + 1);
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily managed with a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) implementation. `SwingWorker`s are useful when you need to "do something" but don't want to block the GUI while doing it. The class also gives you a useful API for communicating back to the EDT when you need to update a GUI component while doing other work via the `publish()/process()` methods.

The below implementation handles your loop on a worker thread so that it does not block the EDT (the GUI thread). Calls to `publish(Integer...)` are relayed to the EDT as a call to `process(List)` which is where you want to update your JProgressBar, because like all Swing components you should only update a JProgressBar on the EDT.

```
public class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    private final int qtd;
    private final JProgressBar progressBar;

    public MySwingWorker(JProgressBar progressBar, int qtd){
        this.qtd = qtd;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    /* This method is called off the EDT so it doesn't block the GUI. */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) { 

            /* This sends the arguments to the process(List) method 
             * so they can be handled on the EDT. */
            publish(i + 1);

            /* Do your stuff. */
            doSomething();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* This method is called on the EDT in response to a 
     * call to publish(Integer...) */
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

You can start it like this

```
int qtd = ...;

progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(qtd);

SwingWorker<? ,?> worker = new MySwingWorker(progressBar, qtd);

worker.execute();
```